# Как сверстать этот элемент с помощью html?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сверстать этот элемент с помощью html?

Comment: Почему именно html, а не svg? Почему именно сверстать, а не вложить обычной картинкой (векторной)?

Comment: Ну как задачу поставили

Comment: Ну использовать инструменты не по назначению — довольно сомнительная задача, если что

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные вещи проще делать с помощью SVG, но раз "задачу поставили" сделать стандартными средствами... Так как конкретные вопросы отсутствуют, то в данном случае проще сделать, чем объяснить:

```css
/* For example only --> */ body{margin:0;height:100vh;background-color:#111;background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png"),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);background-position:0 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;gap:1em}

.wrapper {
  font-size: min(1.7vw, 1.7vh); /* <-- Масштаб */
  position: relative;
  width: 53.1em; height: 53.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0.6em 0.3em #000);
  user-select: none;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 50%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.word:nth-of-type(1) { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
.word:nth-of-type(2) { transform: rotate(45deg);  }
.word:nth-of-type(3) { transform: rotate(90deg);  }
.word:nth-of-type(4) { transform: rotate(135deg); }
.word:nth-of-type(5) { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.word:nth-of-type(6) { transform: rotate(225deg); }
.word:nth-of-type(7) { transform: rotate(270deg); }
.word:nth-of-type(8) { transform: rotate(315deg); }

.word b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  font: 700 4.3em/1em sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.word b:nth-of-type(1) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(-16deg); }
.word b:nth-of-type(2) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(-9.5deg);}
.word b:nth-of-type(3) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(-3deg);  }
.word b:nth-of-type(4) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(3.5deg); }
.word b:nth-of-type(5) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(10deg);  }
.word b:nth-of-type(6) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(16deg);  }
.word b:nth-of-type(7) { transform: translate(-50%, -0.1em) rotate(23deg);  }

.ring {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  width: 42.5em; height: 42.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#111 16.7em, #1110 16.8em), conic-gradient( #39a8de 0deg, #4ee0bd 45deg, #5634eb 135deg, #4a72cf 225deg, #226dff 315deg, #39a8de 360deg);
}

.ring i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;  
  display: block;
  width: 3.9em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.ring i:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 6.1em; transform: translate(-10.5em, -0.2em);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #464fff, #4650ff);
}
.ring i:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 10.5em; transform: translate(-4.7em, -4.6em);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #464ffe, #4063fe);
}
.ring i:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 14.2em; transform: translate(1em, -8.3em);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #3785fd, #2ab3fc);
}
.ring i:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 9em; transform: translate(6.8em, -3.1em);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #2cd0f4, #7ce3bb);
}

@keyframes spin { 100% { transform: rotate(-1turn); } }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
    <div class="word"><b>l</b><b>e</b><b>v</b><b>e</b><b>l</b><b>s</b><b>&bull;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
</div>
```

Как я понял, затруднение возникло в расстановке букв по окружности. В двух словах:
сначала выставляем буквы и точку в одном блоке, чтобы получилось слово, а затем, поворачиваем уже блоки со словами на нужный угол.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Вы лучшие)

Comment: Вопрос, а почему Вы используете в ring <i>? А не div? Возможно что єто строчные элементы?